# [C#]DrawImage will make picture volume bigger

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-core, gdi+

```
var map = new Bitmap("a.jpg");
var w = map.Width;
var h = map.Height;
var _bitmap = new Bitmap(w, h, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Graphics _g = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmap);
var ret = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, map1.Height);
_g.DrawImage(map, ret);
_bitmap.Save("a.jpg");
```

I stitch the picture, 6000px*4000px, source image about 6mb, when my program run over,it bigger 10 times than before, over 60mb. I searched everywhere,but got nothing.

Looking forward your answer.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the example in the [Image.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-image-save(system-string-system-drawing-imaging-imagecodecinfo-system-drawing-imaging-encoderparameters)) documentation for how to save a JPEG frame with a specific quality level.

Comment: System.Drawing is deprecated in .NET Core. It would be far better to use a library like ImageSharp instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot set jpg format

```
bitmap.Save("a.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

problem is solved.

Comment: You should probably add that, without specifying a format, your previous code was generating a PNG image.